# How to customize default styles in @tailwindcss/forms

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

If I use @tailwindcss/forms it will be styled like Unstyled on the following site.
chackbox should look like Simple on the following site.
Currently, when you press down on the checkbox like Unstyled on the site, a border is displayed. I want to eliminate it.

[enter link description here](https://tailwindcss-forms.vercel.app/)

```
  //taiwind.config.js
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/custom-forms'),
  ]
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will have to override the the style for `box-shadow` which is applied on checkbox and radio:

```
[type='checkbox']:focus, [type='radio']:focus {
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: Where should I put the above code?

Comment: You can add an internal styles.css file,  and add the above code in there. Make sure you add reference to styles.css (or import styles) in your app